# Text of Edittext is not visible properly?

Tags: android

In my android login page there is an `EditText` for the password & whenever I put the password, the text is not visible properly. Thank you if someone helps.

```
<EditText
        android:textColorHint="#818080"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rectengle_code"
        android:id="@+id/etEnterCode"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:hint="@string/code"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:inputType="text"
        />
```

Comment: first change height to wrap_content , and can you tell how do you want your text to be??

Comment: Share your snapshot. Also apply some text color to edittext. Also check _rectengle_code_ in which solid color is

Comment: Also, you should change input type to password:

https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/style.html

Comment: What are you asking? A masking option? o_O

Comment: ok i'll inform after try these things...

Comment: actually when i'm putting the password , the password is visible but the the color is so much light....i'm not able to see that properly

Comment: set text color for color in EditText

Comment: Post a screenshot with that behavior.

Comment: thnk u guys my prob. have resolved...the issue was just a text color..special thanks --> Mr. joshi